# getting specific data from map

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

```
Map(1) {
  undefined => Invite {
    code: 'yX4F9sFzDT',
    channel: TextChannel {
      id: '768577451848368129',
      type: 0,
      client: [Client],
      guild: [Guild],
      name: 'invite-the-bot',
      position: 12,
      parentID: '768551919110324237',
      permissionOverwrites: [Collection [Map]],
      rateLimitPerUser: 0,
      topic: null,
      messages: [Collection [Map]],
      lastMessageID: '814571396583129128',
      lastPinTimestamp: null
    }
}
```

code:

```
export async function guildMemberAdd(client: IMClient, guild: Guild, member: Member): Promise<void> {
  if (!client.loaded) return;
  member.guild.getInvites().then(async (guildInvites) => {
    const existingInvites = client.invites.get(member.guild.id);
    console.log(existingInvites);
    const newInvites: Map<string, Invite> = new Map();
    guildInvites.forEach((i) => newInvites.set(i.id, i));
    client.invites.set(member.guild.id, newInvites);
    const invite = guildInvites.find((i) => {
      const tempInvite = existingInvites?.get(i.code);
      if (!tempInvite) return false;
      else {
        console.log(tempInvite);
        return tempInvite && tempInvite.uses < i.uses;
      }
    });
```

Hi.

I'm currently trying to get the `code` from this map. By looping through guildInvites.find and trying to find i.code within this map.
However, I get `undefined` returned. I'm unsure why, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to add a commentary so I've to use the answer.

The invite interface, at least the one you gave, it doesn't have an id, only code. If this is the full interface then in this code:

`guildInvites.forEach((i) => newInvites.set(i.id, i));`

Shouldn't it be:

`guildInvites.forEach((i) => newInvites.set(i.code, i));`.

When you debug does the `newInvites` variable have values?

Comment: Hi. Yes, newInvites does have values.

console.log(tempInvite) is undefined though.